# Issue with Pivot Syntax in Ms Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

The Management studio reports : Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'for'.
PlType start with two types of name, namely : 2 or 4. 
Example : 20H, 20D, 20M, 40H, 40D, 40M, 40X etc. are different types of PlType

```
Select * 
Into #PivotTbl from
(Select Country, PlType , LEFT(PLTYPE,1) as PType
From #ToPivot ) As ToPvt
Pivot
(PlType for PType in (2,4)) As Piv1
```

I don't understand what is the error near 'for'. When I replace

```
(PlType for PType in (2,4)) As Piv1
```

with

```
(max(PlType) for PType in (2,4)) As Piv1
```

I get the error : Incorrect syntax near '2'.
Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 and 4 become columns in the pivot, and you need to surround them in square brackets like so:

```
Select * 
Into #PivotTbl from
(Select Country, PlType , LEFT(PLTYPE,1) as PType
From #ToPivot ) As ToPvt
Pivot
(max(PlType) for PType in ([2],[4])) As Piv1
```

You will get this error even if you don't use `max`. The reason is that you must use an aggregate function along with `pivot`.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. But please can you also tell me, why do I have to provide an aggregate function for Pivot. I mean 'max' in
(max(PlType) for PType in ([2],[4])) As Piv1

Comment: It should be working with

Pivot
(PlType for PType in ([2],[4])) As Piv1

because PlType is of varchar type. But is shows error.

Comment: The docs clearly state that an aggregate function is needed. I suppose this is because pivot operation is used for summarising, which would require an aggregation to be performed on teh data.